# RecyclerVIew cargado por Spinner genera bucle infinito

Tags: java, android, firebase, recyclerview, android-spinner

estoy tratando de realizar una tienda y para realizar la busqueda avanzada de los productos estoy utilizando 3 spinners, la cosa es que cuando usaba 2 de ellos funcionaba perfectamente pero al meter el tercero, me ha generado un bucle infinito. El recycler se carga realizando una busqueda en firebase con los datos recogidos desde los spinner. Aquí dejo mi código donde realizo las interacciones para ver si alguien me puede ayudar.

**BusquedaAvanzadaFragment**

```
public class FilterFragment extends Fragment
implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{


public FilterFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

String txtMarca,txtTipo;
String txtSubTipo = "subtipos";
Spinner spinMarca,spinTipo, spinSubTipo;
RecyclerView rv;
List<String>Marcas;
List<String>Tipos;
List<Producto> productoslist;
AdapterAllProducts adapterAllProducts;
public DatabaseReference mReferencia;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.filter_fragment, container, false);
    spinMarca=v.findViewById(R.id.spinnerMarca);
    spinTipo=v.findViewById(R.id.spinnerTipoPieza);
    spinSubTipo=v.findViewById(R.id.spinnerSubtipo);
    rv=v.findViewById(R.id.rvAvanzado);
    Marcas = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.marcas));
    Tipos = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tiposPiezas));
    mReferencia= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Producto");
    spinMarca.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    spinTipo.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    spinSubTipo.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    return v;
}


public void cargarRecycler(final String Marca, String Tipo, final String SubTipo){
    Log.e("TAG", "Estoy en el metodo");
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    productoslist= new ArrayList<>();
    adapterAllProducts = new AdapterAllProducts(productoslist,getActivity());
    adapterAllProducts.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Producto prod = productoslist.get(rv.getChildAdapterPosition(v));
            String pid = prod.getPid();
            String nombre = prod.getNombre();
            String desc = prod.getDescripcion();
            String ref = prod.getReferencia();
            float pre = (float)prod.getPrecio();
            int cant = prod.getCantidad();
            String marca = prod.getMarca();
            String tipo = prod.getTipo();
            String subTipo = prod.getSubtipo();
            Preferencias.setPid(getActivity(),pid);
            Preferencias.setNombreProd(getActivity(),nombre);
            Preferencias.setPrecio(getActivity(),pre);
            Preferencias.setReferencia(getActivity(),ref);
            Preferencias.setDesc(getActivity(),desc);
            Preferencias.setCantidad(getActivity(),cant);
            Preferencias.setMarca(getActivity(),marca);
            Preferencias.setTipo(getActivity(),tipo);
            Preferencias.setSubTipo(getActivity(),subTipo);

            Fragment fragmentuser = new ProductsFragment();
            FragmentManager ManagerUser = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transactionUser = ManagerUser.beginTransaction();
            transactionUser.replace(R.id.contentfragment,fragmentuser);
            transactionUser.commit();

        }
    });
    rv.setAdapter(adapterAllProducts);

    if (Marca.equals("Marcas")&&Tipo.equals("Tipos")&&SubTipo.equals("subtipos")){
        mReferencia.child("Producto").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                productoslist.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot Snapshot : snapshot.getChildren()
                ) {
                    Producto producto = Snapshot.getValue(Producto.class);
                    productoslist.add(producto);

                }
                adapterAllProducts.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }else{
        if(!Marca.equals("Marcas")&&Tipo.equals("Tipos")&&SubTipo.equals("subtipos")){
            Query q = mReferencia.orderByChild("marca").equalTo(Marca);
            q.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                    productoslist.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot Snapshot : snapshot.getChildren()
                    ) {
                        Producto producto = Snapshot.getValue(Producto.class);
                        productoslist.add(producto);
                    }
                    adapterAllProducts.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
        }
        else if (Marca.equals("Marcas") && !Tipo.equals("Tipos")&&SubTipo.equals("subtipos")){
            Query q = mReferencia.orderByChild("tipo").equalTo(Tipo);
            q.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                    productoslist.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot Snapshot : snapshot.getChildren()
                    ) {
                        Producto producto = Snapshot.getValue(Producto.class);
                        productoslist.add(producto);
                    }
                    adapterAllProducts.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
        }
        else if (Marca.equals("Marcas") && !Tipo.equals("Tipos")&&!SubTipo.equals("subtipos")){
            Query q = mReferencia.orderByChild("tipo").equalTo(Tipo);
            q.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                    productoslist.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot Snapshot : snapshot.getChildren()
                    ) {
                        Producto producto = Snapshot.getValue(Producto.class);
                        if (producto.getSubtipo().equals(SubTipo)) {
                            productoslist.add(producto);
                        }
                    }
                    adapterAllProducts.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
        }
        else if (!Marca.equals("Marcas") && !Tipo.equals("Tipos")&&!SubTipo.equals("subtipos")){
            Query q = mReferencia.orderByChild("tipo").equalTo(Tipo);
            q.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                    productoslist.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot Snapshot : snapshot.getChildren()
                    ) {
                        Producto producto = Snapshot.getValue(Producto.class);
                        if (producto.getMarca().equals(Marca)){
                            if (producto.getSubtipo().equals(SubTipo)) {
                                productoslist.add(producto);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    adapterAllProducts.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
        }
    }

}


public String RellenospinSubTipo(String subTipo){
    switch (subTipo){
        case "Motor":
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),R.array.subtipos_motor,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinSubTipo.setAdapter(adapter);
            txtSubTipo = spinSubTipo.getSelectedItem().toString();
            break;
        case "Frenos":
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),R.array.subtipos_frenos,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinSubTipo.setAdapter(adapter1);
            txtSubTipo = spinSubTipo.getSelectedItem().toString();
            break;
        case "Suspensión":
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),R.array.subtipos_suspen,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinSubTipo.setAdapter(adapter2);
            txtSubTipo = spinSubTipo.getSelectedItem().toString();
            break;
        case "Merchandising":
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter3 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),R.array.subtipos_merch,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinSubTipo.setAdapter(adapter3);
            txtSubTipo = spinSubTipo.getSelectedItem().toString();
            break;
    }
    return txtSubTipo;
}
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    txtMarca = spinMarca.getSelectedItem().toString();
    txtTipo = spinTipo.getSelectedItem().toString();
    cargarRecycler(txtMarca,txtTipo,RellenospinSubTipo(txtTipo));
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

}}
```

Estaré agradecido a cualquiera que me pueda ayudar a ver donde esta el problema. He estado mirandolo y al parecer es el tercer spinner al meterle el onItemSelected. Pero si alguien sabe como hacerlo, se lo agradecería.
Un saludo

Comment: CargarRecycler solo tiene que haber logica y ejecucion de funciones que actualizen el estado del recycler, no inicializacion de alguna vista, veo que tienes setlayoutmanager del recycler view, asi como el adapter, estas haciendo q cada rato sea como un creacion de vista, puede causar errores, si se ejecuta mas rapido.

Comment: Intenta hacer instancias de los Adapters como parte de la clase y no crearlas local. Al asignar un Adapter se detona el evento de onItemSelected y hace que se ejecute múltiples veces porque siempre se actualiza el Adapter de manera repetitiva en el evento. Los adapters debes crearlo y asignarlo una sola vez y jugar solo con su colección o lista, limpiando, agregando y eliminando para luego notificarle a cada Adapter con notifyDataSetChanged. Si no quieres que se detone onItemSelected en un momento en específico puedes deshabilitarlo con `setOnItemSelectedListener(null)` limpia y arregla.

Comment: @OsAndNoTi por lo que he visto a pesar de que ese cambio es necesario para la optimizacion del código, el bucle me lo genera el switch en el que establezco el contenido del tercer spinner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUCIONADO**

Al final tras mirar todo lo que se me comentaba y demás me he dado cuenta del error. Todo era cosa del  `onItemSelectedListener` , al final lo he solucionado cambiando el contenido del metodo por  un switch

Aquí dejo el ejemplo de lo que a mi me ha servido

```
   @Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    switch (adapterView.getId()){
        case R.id.spinnerMarca:
            txtMarca = spinMarca.getSelectedItem().toString();
            txtTipo = spinTipo.getSelectedItem().toString();
            cargarRecycler(txtMarca,txtTipo,txtSubTipo);
            break;
        case R.id.spinnerTipoPieza:
            txtMarca = spinMarca.getSelectedItem().toString();
            txtTipo = spinTipo.getSelectedItem().toString();
            RellenospinSubTipo(txtTipo);
            cargarRecycler(txtMarca,txtTipo,txtSubTipo);
            break;

        case R.id.spinnerSubtipo:
            txtMarca = spinMarca.getSelectedItem().toString();
            txtTipo = spinTipo.getSelectedItem().toString();
            txtSubTipo = spinSubTipo.getSelectedItem().toString();
            cargarRecycler(txtMarca,txtTipo,txtSubTipo);
            break;
    }




}
```